# How to draw a specific shape in CSS?

Tags: css, draw, shapes, css-shapes

I have **shape** as the image here. I don't how to draw it in CSS.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/jmhzhbzcx/]

Can any body help me to draw it?
thanks

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break your shape up in smaller shapes. You could do something like this:

1. Draw a square to serve as the main body for your shape
2. Draw three triangles in different sizes to overlap the square in your background color.

By hiding certain parts of your square you can create a lot of new shapes.

For examples of basic shapes to use as building blocks, take a look over here for instance (or just Google for 'css shapes'):
http://www.css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Though using SVG might make more sense for these kind of shapes, this is an example in HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ozpfgnrm/

```css
/* top shape */
 #div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid white;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
#div3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid white;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
#div4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 150px solid white;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}

/* bottom shape to show what is going on */
 #div5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 120px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
#div6 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 120px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-right: 20px solid green;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#div7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 120px;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-left: 20px solid green;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#div8 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 120px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid green;
    border-left: 150px solid red;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<!-- Top shape -->
<div id="div1"></div>    
<div id="div2"></div>    
<div id="div3"></div>    
<div id="div4"></div>

<!-- bottom shape to show what is going on -->
<div id="div5"></div>    
<div id="div6"></div>    
<div id="div7"></div>    
<div id="div8"></div>
```